Django Object Storage doesn't reflect into my Object Storage
I'm attempting to integrate an Object Storage into my Django project, and my current setup includes Django, DRF, and PostgreSQL. Specifically, I'm attempting to handle an image upload from an API endpoint and store it in the Object Storage.
class Announcement(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')

Now when I try to access the API endpoint for the operation. The image is stored somewhere in my base_dir/media.
and here's my boto3\storage setup
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('DO_SPACES_KEY')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('DO_SPACES_SECRET')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('DO_SPACES_BUCKET')
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = os.environ.get('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT')
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_LOCATION = 'media'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'



I tried reconfiguring the settings but had no success. I also checked the credentials, mediafiles, and runtime values of the data.
I also checked the postgresql database, which contains what appears to be the image's URL in my object storage.

What you actually need to do is to change the way you're implementing your
models by converting it to a binary.
So that it becomes:
class Announcements(models.Model): 
image = model.BinaryField()

This way you can store it directly.
